# Getting track cues doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, html5-video

I have a small problem with IE and video  `track`  element. I have a video elelemnt with captions. To display captions I get track element

`var trackElement = this.template.find("track")[0];`

and then extract cues with `.track`

`this.textTrack = trackElement.track;`

And that's what I get back with `this.textTrack`

[image]

The thing is `.track` doesn't work in IE. And that what I get back with `this.textTrack` in IE.

[image]
I wonder why `.track` is not supported in IE? And how can I fix it, to get cues data in IE?

Edit: `.track` is working corectly in IE. The problem is it always return empty track object unless you try it for example on `cuechange` event which is not what I want. Empty `.track` is a common problem and many dev's post similar questions over the web.

Comment: its nit widely supported. check out caniuse http://caniuse.com/#search=track

Comment: I think this could be a problem with my code as I found working example .track on IE website https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772673(v=vs.85).aspx#code-snippet-2

Comment: This is a timing issue. You must wait until the texttracks cues are loaded.